# Writing modular ECMAScript that runs in browsers AND in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm new to heavy lifting in Javascript and node.js. I've been writing some client side stuff with the Web Audio Api, all quick and dirty/monolithic experiments but now I want to do some actual projects. I don't fancy this whole in browser testing thing and I've heard plenty of people use node for their testing so I'd like to do the same, using grunt for automation. This is in part so I can decompose my code into many nice small testable chunks which can then be gathered up into one or two big blobs and served.

Hitherto I've just been splitting my javascript into files and importing it in sequence at the bottom of a body tag. Obvs this works for small client side projects but it is not scalable.

What I'm more use to is an import mechanism like in pretty much every other language, and like what node.js has. However the browser doesn't know about exports or module.exports and will barf as soon as it sees it.

Two obvious solutions spring to mind but both seem smelly to me...

1) Put exports = module.exports = {}; in the head of every page.

2) Find and remove these export declarations when compiling all the files together.

Neither of these feel like good solutions.

Are there any canonical solutions/patterns I should know about for making modular code in JS? If not does anyone have a moderately elegant one? And failing that does anyone have one that doesn't suck too bad!? Should I be learning RequireJS? Will ES6 modules solve this issue and, if so, should I just wait for better support? Sorry to ask so many questions at once, the JS ecosystem is proving both thrilling and bewildering!

Comment: Look up Browserify. It lets you compile code using CommonJS (`var thing = require('./thing.js')`) into a single file that you can run in the browser. The goal of ES6 modules is to eventually fix this, yes.

Comment: I'd look into Babel and ES6.  It's the future and AMD (and all it's shims) will likely go to the wayside.

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked how Kris Kowal et. al. did it in the Q library--and his comments in that section of code are impeccable

https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js

Comment: That's nicely done. Ideally I'd like to avoid adding a couple of dozen lines of boilerplate to every module I make but I guess with things being as they are this is one of the better options.